# In Matlab, why sometimes stepwise regress gives more coefficients than predictors number

Tags: matlab, regression, linear-regression

I have 129 variables, using "stepwiselm" to regress.

lm_mod = stepwiselm(lm_x,lm_y,'Criterion','aic');

lm_x have 100 rows and 129 colums. The model give result that includeing 41 predictors, but give 98 regression cooefficients. I cannot understand why coefficients more than predictors. The extra is like this in the following picture.
[model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5379P.jpg)[cooefficients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iazg.jpg)

Comment: I don't know what you mean in the picture. There are 58, right?